# Configure email notification in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I am trying to configure Hudson to send an email if a build fails to the person who committed the broken build to SVN.

### Question

Is it possible to do this and if so how do I configure Hudson to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes - in your job configuration, check E-mail Notification under Build Settings near the bottom of the page, and then also check "Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build" to have Hudson email the person(s) who committed the SVN changes for a failed build.  Note that your Hudson user names will need to match your SVN user names in order for this to work properly.

If you want to have certain people receive email whenever a build breaks or is fixed, regardless of whether they caused the failure, add their email addresses to the Recipients field.

You don't need the email-ext plugin to do this, but that plugin does give you a lot more control over the email format and content.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible, and I do this in my organization.  See:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin

*quoting:*
This plugin allows you to configure every aspect of email notifications.  You can customize when an email is sent, who should receive it, and what the email says.

This plugin extends Hudson's built in email notification functionality by giving you more control.  It provides customization of 3 areas.

•Triggers - Select the conditions that should cause an email notification to be sent.
•Content - Specify the content of each triggered email's subject and body.
•Recipients - Specify who should receive a email when it is triggered.

The trigger you want to select is the "Failure" trigger, and be sure to check the "Send to Committers" checkbox.