# Setup email notification when unit tests fail

Tags: teamcity

I have a big project. And I want to receive email when I (and only I) commit code which broke unit test. We have TeamCity project which run all unit tests (it takes more than 5 hours). And I have 2 problems to setup it:

1. Project has already broken tests (these tests will be fixed but not now). And I want receive email only when I broke new tests. And I don't want receive email when fail old tests.
2. To check all tests take a lot of time (near 5-6 hours). For this time many developers commit changes. So when team city run unit tests, there are more then 30 changes (and more than 30 different developers can make this changes). And only 1 developer broke test, and I want that only this 1 developer receive email but not all 30.

How can I do that? If someone have some idea or advice, I will be very appreciate. 
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email user that broke build in Teamcity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180772/email-user-that-broke-build-in-teamcity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any CI system that gives you specific commit that fails tests (I know one plugin that is in development for Jenkins right now).

There are already notification by email for broken build. I don't think that it should be specific person because the quality is responsibility of all team.

I see issue with project structure:
1) Fix or ignore failed tests
2) Separate unit tests from integration tests. Run them separately
3) Break project into submodules with corresponded tests. This will reduce number of comitters as well reduce time of feedback loop

Comment: What's the name of the plugin? I'm looking for the same for Hudson. Maybe that one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3041474/60462?