# Jenkins Extended E-mail failed to send email with attachment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, email-ext

I am trying to send my test report from Jenkins to email using emailext plugin and I can send email without attachment, but if I attach any document it fails.

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: "**/*.html", body: 'Test', subject: 'Android App', to: "myemail@test.com"
```

**Error Message**

```
Sending email to: myemail@test.com
Error sending to the following VALID addresses: myemail@test.com
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Error sending to the following VALID addresses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jenkins Error sending to the following INVALID addresses:xxx@yyy.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829216/jenkins-error-sending-to-the-following-invalid-addressesxxxyyy-com)

Comment: Shared question is reported for error "Error sending to the following INVALID addresses", I can send email without attachment.

Comment: See the answers, you probably have a confirguration problem.